# Filtering eager-loaded data in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following setup:

Clubs offer Activities, which are of a particular Type, so 3 models with relationships:

Club:

```
function activities()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Activity');
}
```

Activity:

```
function club()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Club');
}

function activityType()
{
    return $this->hasMany('ActivityType');
}
```

ActivityType:

```
function activities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Activity');
}
```

So for example Club Foo might have a single Activity called 'Triathlon' and that Activity has ActivityTypes 'Swimming', 'Running', and 'Cycling'.

This is all fair enough but I need to show a list of ActivityTypes on the Club page - basically just a list. So I need to get the ActivityTypes of all the related Activities.

I can do that like so from a controller method that receives an instance of the Club model:

```
$data = $this->club->with(array('activities', 'activities.activityTypes'))->find($club->id)
```

That gets me an object with all the related Activities along with the ActivityTypes related to them. Also fair enough. But I need to apply some more filtering. An Activity might not be in the right status (it could be in the DB as a draft entry or expired), so I need to be able to only get the ActivityTypes of the Activities that are live and in the future.

At this point I'm lost... does anybody have any suggestions for handling this use case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter, you can use `where()` as in the fluent DB queries:

```
$data = Club::with(array('activities' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('activity_start', '>', DB::raw('current_time'));

}))->activityType()->get();
```

The example which served as inspiration for this is in the laravel docs, check the end of this section: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

*(the code's not tested, and I've taken some liberties with the property names! :) )*

Answer (score 0):

I think if you first constraint your relationship of activities, the activity types related to them will be automatically constrained as well.

So what I would do is

```
function activities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Activity')->where('status', '=', 'active');
}
```

and then your

```
$data = $this->club->with(array('activities', 'activities.activityTypes'))->find($club->id)`
```

query will be working as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks - I went with a different answer as the approach you suggested would mean that I could only ever retrieve active Activities via the activities() model method. Using the filter means I can also get those with a status of 'pending' or whatever else.